# converting multiple LINQ queries into 1?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to convert this code into one LINQ query. I could have sworn I had done something like this before, but I cannot figure out where I might that code might be. I want to perform a sub query and modify the values of the selected items if one list has values from another.

```
var selectInstructors = _instructorService.GetAllNonGuestInstructors()
                                          .Select(i => new SelectListItem()
                                                       {
                                                           Text = i.User.ToFullName(),
                                                           Value = i.Id.ToString() 
                                                       }).ToList();

var selectedItems = schedule.Instructors
                        .Select(instructior1 => selectInstructors.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Value == instructior1.Id.ToString()))
                        .Where(selectedItem => selectedItem != null);

foreach (var selectedItem in selectedItems )
{
    selectInstructors.Remove(selectedItem);
    selectedItem.Selected = true;
    selectInstructors.Add(selectedItem);
}
```

So let's assume in the `selectInstructors` list  I have these values:
John Smith, 1
Jane Doe, 2
Dave Ritter, 3
(before we iterate the persisted instructors the `selected` Boolean value is a default of false)

The `schedule.Instructors` class has the persisted list of instructors for that schedule:
John Smith, 1
Dave Ritter, 3

Now, what I would like to do is set any of the `Selected` properties in `selectInstructors` where the value is equal to `schedule.Instructors`

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve? i.e. which entities are involved, what their relationships are and what your output should be? The code is quite confusing...

Comment: @Spikeh, I thought it would be obvious I am working with a SelectList collection and want to set a Boolean value if the ID of the complete list matches the ID value from a similar list. I'll update the question I suppose. Not sure why the down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var selectedIds = schedule.Instructors.Select(i => i.Id.ToString()).ToList();    

var instructors = (from instructor in _instructorService.GetAllNonGuestInstructors()
                   let value = instructor.Id.ToString()
                   select new SelectListItem()
                   {
                       Text = instructor.User.ToFullName(),
                       Value = value,
                       Selected = selectedIds.Contains(value)
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
            var allInstructors = _instructorService.GetAllNonGuestInstructors();
        if(allInstructors!=null)
            allInstructors.Select(i =>
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = i.User.ToFullName(), Value = i.Id.ToString() }).
                    Zip(schedule.Instructors,(selectedItems,instructor)=>
                    {var item = selectedItems.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Value == instructior.Id.ToString());
                        if(item!=null)
                            item.Selected=true;});
      //Now use allInstructors collection further it will have Selected true according to your conditions.
```

I can't understand one thing why selectedItem is removed and then added. Anyways I hope this will help.

Comment: I was only removing it from the collection so that I could update that item in the selectInstructors collection. It was sloppy way of just performing the update until I could figure out what you provided!